# Adobe AIR Mobile: эффект взрыва

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, air, apache-flex

Имеется игра, на `AS3` во `Flash Builder` (без использования `Flex framework`).
И в эту игру нужно добавить анимацию взрывов.

UPD: Игра для мобильных устройств (`iOS, Android`) на `AIR`

Вернее, она уже добавлена, но на средне-слабых устройствах тормозит...
Добавлена при помощи `swf` файла, который и представляет из себя анимацию взрыва, и воспроизводится через `MovieClip`.

Интересует самый оптимизированный способ анимации взрыва...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Векторная анимация действительно тормозит на устройствах.

- 1 способ ) - Перевести анимацию в набор битмапов, выводить покадрово, например через `copyPixels()`
- 2 способ ) - Использовать фреймворк `Starling`, выводить всю графику/анимацию через него (расово верный способ)

Comment: спасибо за ответ!
1 способ по производительности такой же, как и мой
а посмотрев демку старлинга, увидел, что они требуют флеш плеер 11.4, и понял, что забыл указать, что игра для мобильных устройств(iOS, Android) на AIR.

Comment: Так Starling как раз для мобильных устройств и создавался, AIR 3.4 минимум ему нужен.

Comment: а, ну, спасибо! наверно в текущем проекте не буду ничего уже переделывать, а в следующем начну с него!